# Return value from $.Ajax call is not shown in the page source

Tags: jquery

Can someone tell me why the return value from $.Ajax call is not shown in the page source
I am new to jQuery.  I am simply return a string from $.ajax function and displaying that string value as HTML for a  tag or

tag.

Here is my jquery code
..................................................

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "AdvService.asmx/GetValuesTesting",
    data: "{}",
    context: document.body,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: OnSuccess,
    error: OnError
});
   function OnSuccess(data, status) {

   alert(data.d);
    $('#dataInTag').html(data.d);
}
function OnError(request, status, error) {
    alert(request.status);
}
    });
```

****html section***

```
<pre>
    <div>
        <p id="dataInTag"></p>
    </div>
    </pre>
```

*** WebMethod ****

```
[WebMethod]
    public string GetValuesTesting()
    {

        string Details = "<b class=\"testClass\">returned data from a WebMethod</b>";
        return Details;
    }
```

How can I assign a jquery click event to this return value (this is a b tag with class="testClass").

alert is prompted well but the returned value is shown on page but does not appear in page Source.
Please help...
and thanks in advance...

Comment: You need to post code before anyone can help.

Comment: Can you post some code or rephrase your question.  It's not clear what you want to accomplish.

Comment: put your code whatever you tried and not working

Answer (score 2):

You should not expect to see the results of an AJAX call show up in the page source.  AJAX is dynamic and in only in memory.

You may be able to see if if you use a debugger.  For example if you use chrome and look at the developer tools page it will show the page source with changes made by AJAX calls.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method you won't see the modified HTML if you browse the source code of the page. The DOM is correctly modified but when you look at the source code you see the initial version. Luckily users see what the browser displays, not the source code. If you inspect the DOM with [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) you will see the changes.